# How do I keep a .pdf open/quickly accessible

Tags: google-drive, pdf, recents-screen

When I open a .pdf, such as a longer article, I'd like to keep it open, in the sense that it's available in the recent apps list. How do I do that?

The problem in more detail: say I open article.pdf with the default drive .pdf viewer. I read a part of the article, and then do something else on my phone. Later, maybe the next day, I'd like to continue reading where I left off. However, by this time the pdf viewer has dropped out of the recent apps list, and then only obvious way to find the file again is go find article.pdf from the downloads folder and open it again. In the worst case, the viewer has forgotten where I left off and I need to scroll through the file to find the right place to continue.

Comment: You could try pinning the app on the recent apps list if your device/OS supports it. However, the Android system may kill the app at any moment when it's in the background. The feasible solution is to use other PDF reader apps that support remembering last position (I haven't researched any).

Comment: @andrewt I'm in Android 10, and the only pinning I can find is screen pinning, which pins the app to the screen, instead of pinning it to the recent apps list. Is there some other pinning which I'm missing?

Comment: as suggested, install any ebook reader